# MS Access Enable Macro Content

Tags: ms-access

Are there instances when you already enabled the macro content of your MS Access Application, it will be disabled again?

**Security Warning which prompts to enable the macro content.**

[image]

**This is how I enabled the macro content of our MS Access App.**

[image]

Comment: This is a setting each Access install must accomplish. It is not a setting for a particular database. Unless a database has a digital signature.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the directory the database is stored in to your trusted locations.  See this link:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-7EE1CDC2-483E-4CBB-BCB3-4E7C67147FB4